# calculations after the docplex solution

Tags: optimization, python, docplex

After solving the problem with docplex and having the decision variables' values, can I do some calculations in the code with decision variables?

```
mdl.print_information()
sol = mdl.solve()
mdl.print_solution()
```

I mean can I have use the decision variables and calculate something after the code above?

Comment: After solving the model, I assume the problem would be solved in an optimal sense, you can still retrieve the decision variables value and performing your favours post-processing. Is it what you are looking for?

Comment: Yes but I need to calculate some equations with knowing the value of decision varlables.

Comment: What do you mean by "calculate some equations"? If you mean do arithmetic in Python using the values of the decision variables, that is what @A.Omidi said in his comment.

Answer (score 1):

With docplex as with other cplex API you can do postprocess.

For instance, in the [zoo example](https://www.linkedin.com/pulse/making-optimization-simple-python-alex-fleischer/)

```
from docplex.mp.model import Model

mdl = Model(name='buses')
nbbus40 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus40')
nbbus30 = mdl.integer_var(name='nbBus30')
mdl.add_constraint(nbbus40*40 + nbbus30*30 >= 300, 'kids')
mdl.minimize(nbbus40*500 + nbbus30*400)

mdl.solve()

print("nb buses (40 seats and 30 seats) = ",int(nbbus40.solution_value+nbbus30.solution_value))
```

gives

```
nb buses (40 seats and 30 seats) =  8
```